# Was Eden different from the rest of the world?

Tags: genesis, creation, death, garden-of-eden

Gen 2:8

> The LORD God planted a garden eastward in Eden, and there He put the man whom He had formed.

This could sound like Eden was a special place, planted after Adam's creation, and different from the rest of the world. Specifically, in Eden there was apparently no death of any kind - but was this true for the rest of the world?

I am assuming all plants, animals, insects, fish, and micro-life had already been created prior to Eden. So many life forms are designed to consume living prey or the decay of dead life forms (plant and animal). I would also assume that God created them this way. But that would mean death had to exist outside the Garden of Eden, or all those species would die. *OR* there were special circumstances that allowed those metabolisms to exist on other diets. And any naturally short-lived species would just not die.

I know many people have made their views and conjectures known. But are there any scriptures that support either side of this question?

Comment: There's a little discussion [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6934/are-questions-asking-for-verse-searches-salvageable-or-off-topic/6935#6935) as to why your question is off-topic for the site.

Comment: Peter: Thank you so much for letting me in on that discussion. I would have had no clue what was going on! This was simply a question that came up in a conversation. I did a verse search, but could not find anything that shed any light on that particular angle. So I thought to ask others who studied more deeply than simple verse searches, and might know of references I had missed. I'm aware there are various traditions and schools of thought, but I wanted to know if the Bible itself said anything about this. Is there a better way to frame such a question?

Comment: If you're a non-denominational Christian, I understand it can be a little hard.  This website is more about Christian doctrine.  We have a [sister site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) devoted to delving into Bible verses.  So, if you're question is, does this verse indicate Eden was a special place - that's a good site to ask on.   Otherwise, if you can cite where you heard that "there was no death of any kind" in Eden, then you can edit it in here and we'll have a frame of reference.  We just try to narrow questions like "are there any scriptures..." before they attract answers

Comment: I have been on that site before. I assumed it was more for questions about the texts and languages than scriptures as a whole. So I thought a more "general" question would be better here. Thanks for helping me with this. Greatly apreciate the boost!!  :8>)